# WebView doesn't return YouTube video in Xcode 7.x [W/Code+Images]

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, webview

I'm building a video player app in Swift 2 that will load 3 videos which data (title, description, thumbnail and video url) are saved in a global array named `videos`.

This app consists in a Table View that has 3 cells and when the user clicks in one the Video Player View will open. I configured it to have a Web View that will play a youtube video. I know I can do this in a better way with the YouTube API but right now I'm focusing on only using this 3 videos.

I created a new Cocoa Touch Class file named `PlayerViewController.swift` and in it I configured the Video Player. 
The class of the Video Player View in the `Main.storyboard` is set to `PlayerViewController`.

The labels are working fine but the WebView just doesn't load, I can move it around but no video at all.
What am I doing wrong? Do I have to set any class for the Web View? How can I make the videos play in this WebView correctly?
The code is down below.

Thanks in advance!

Player View Controller:

```
//import Foundation
import UIKit
//import WebKit
//import AVFoundation

class PlayerViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var videoView: UIWebView!

    @IBOutlet weak var playerTitle: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var playerDescription: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        videoView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true

        videoView.loadHTMLString("<iframe width=\"\(videoView.frame.width)\" height=\"\(videoView.frame.height)\" src=\"\(videos[activeVideo]["video"])?&playsinline=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", baseURL: nil)

        playerTitle.text = videos[activeVideo]["title"]
        playerDescription.text = videos[activeVideo]["description"]
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

View Controller:

```
import UIKit

var videos = [Dictionary<String,String>()]

var activeVideo = -1

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if videos.count == 1 {

            videos.removeAtIndex(0)

            // Check if places != to 1 and not 0 because we created the dictionary places as a global var outside the ViewController and that can not be empty.

            videos.append(["title":"Video 1","description":"Description 1","thumbnail":"http://img.youtube.com/vi/6oXTFb-52Zc/0.jpg","video":"https://www.youtube.com/embed/6oXTFb-52Zc"])
            videos.append(["title":"Video 2","description":"Description 2","thumbnail":"http://img.youtube.com/vi/dkwuCeCQVg8/0.jpg","video":"https://www.youtube.com/embed/dkwuCeCQVg8"])
            videos.append(["title":"Video 3","description":"Description 3","thumbnail":"http://img.youtube.com/vi/6Zf_70xM1Cw/0.jpg","video":"https://www.youtube.com/embed/v=6Zf_70xM1Cw"])

        }

    }

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return videos.count

    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

        let url = NSURL(string: videos[indexPath.row]["thumbnail"]!)
            let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)

        cell.img?.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        cell.ttl?.text = videos[indexPath.row]["title"]
        cell.dsc?.text = videos[indexPath.row]["description"]

        return cell

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {

        activeVideo = indexPath.row

        return indexPath
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "back" {

            activeVideo = -1

            // Resetting the value of activeVideo

        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

[Empty WebView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwOqU.png)

[Main.storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WF2pq.png)

Comment: Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: No errors... Just an empty WebView that moves around :(

Comment: I see that in your Player View Controller the string being set on 'videoView.loadHTMLString' is not properly escaped. If that is in your actual code you will have an issue. This-> ideo]["video"])?&playsinline <- should probably be [\"video\"]. No?

Comment: I tried doing that but I got more errors... I think that since the ["video"] is already inside a \() it should not need to be escaped.

Comment: *Inside a slash parenthesis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had also kind of this problem. Instead of this line:

```
videoView.loadHTMLString("<iframe width=\"\(videoView.frame.width)\" height=\"\(videoView.frame.height)\" src=\"\(videos[activeVideo]["video"])?&playsinline=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", baseURL: nil)
```

try to use the below:

```
videoView.loadHTMLString("<html><style type=\"text/css\">body{margin:0px;padding:0px;}</style><script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'></script><script type='text/javascript'>function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){ytplayer=new YT.Player('playerId',{events:{onReady:onPlayerReady}})}function onPlayerReady(a){a.target.playVideo();}</script><body><iframe id='playerId' type='text/html' width='\(videoView.frame.width)' height='\(videoView.frame.height)' src='\(videos[activeVideo]["video"])?enablejsapi=0&rel=0&playsinline=1&autoplay=1' frameborder='0'></body></html>", baseURL: nil)
```

**Edit:**

Checking again your code I realise that you don't call anywhere the playerViewController. Place all the code you have in viewDidLoad() of PayerViewController in cellForIndexPath. You should add a webView in cell to work. On the other hand if you want to keep the UI like this to retrieve the image you should make an asynchronous call like this:

```
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string:imageURL())!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in

  if let dataImage = data {
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
         let image: UIImage? = UIImage(data: dataImage)
             if let _ = image {
                cell.image.image = image!
             }
     })          
   } else {
   }
})
task.resume()
```

The UI is on the main thread, so when you get the asynchronous response you have to attach it on the main_thread.

Comment: Hey thank you for your reply! :) However now I'm getting errors, you can see them here: [link](http://imgur.com/w4tkV15). 
The playsinline is something that I saw in this video tutorial [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rg6GLVUnnpM)  so I don't understand why you use that and enablejsapi as they were variables. Can you please have a look?

Comment: Oh yeah, it was my fault I forgot to remove some variable I had on my code. Now I changed it. You can copy paste it.

Comment: Thank you so much again! But, it seems that it must be something else because I still get the same empty WebView :( You can see it here: [link](http://imgur.com/J3NWL6f)

Comment: Thank you for your support! :) I tried this and got an error because the `videoView` outlet was only defined in the PlayerViewController and I was trying to put it inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath in the ViewController. Then I remembered to try using a + inside the `videoView.loadHTMLString` to add the string inside the array `videos` and it worked fine! 

Like this: `videoView.loadHTMLString("<iframe width=\"\(videoView.frame.width)\" height=\"\(videoView.frame.height)\" src=\"" + videos[activeVideo]["video"]! + "\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", baseURL: nil)`

Comment: I don't understand why it works with + but not with slash(), but the video is running now! :)

 It was good to get to know your insights and alternatives, so I accepted this answer!

I'm now trying to make the video frame fit the entire web view because although I set the frame width and heigh they are not working properly. Image: [link](http://imgur.com/HjQQwen)

I'm new here so I don't know if I have to create a new question just for this. Hope it is ok!

Comment: for this you can try to disable the scrollView of webView:

   ``webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false``

Comment: Thank you so much :) And sorry for the delay!